# Wifi frequent disconnection and reconnection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My laptop disconnects from wifi for a second, then reconnects. In another 13 - 30 seconds this will happen again. On and on and on. The wifi connection icon in the lower right (systray) would flicker to the globe icon [image] then back to connected again [image]. This is causing huge problem for video calls.

I have been trying to find the cause of this problem:

1. My wife's laptop and my son's laptop connecting to the same wifi hotspot don't have this problem. Our cell phones don't have this problem.
2. I have called Lenovo support. They suspected the laptop's wifi adapter has problem (ThinkPad T14). They swapped the motherboard of the laptop (wifi adapter is in the motherboard). They also updated BIOS and drivers. The problem persists.
3. I asked IT for a laptop replacement. The replacement laptop also has the same problem (same model).
4. I have turned off the router, turned it on again. Problem persists.
5. I have run `netsh int ip reset`, `netsh advfirewall reset`, `netsh winsock reset`, `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /renew`. Problem persists.
6. I tried to tether to my phone internet. No disconnection!
7. The problem started this week. Last week the laptop didn't have this problem.

What else should I check?

Comment: I bet the problem is hardware or configuration related, but just in case, to rule out interference issues: does this also occur when the laptop occupies the exact same location as one of the other devices that does have a stable connection? Even relatively small objects can cause this, if they contain sufficient metal.

Comment: @MiG thanks for the suggestion. I'll try moving the laptop to a different location.

Comment: I've had a similar problem in the past that was caused by IP collision (2 machines having the same IP).

Comment: Check [Lenovo Support downloads](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/) for updates that you might not have.

Comment: Good point, check if any of these devices are configured with a fixed IP (rather than DHCP). Especially wife's and son's laptops :]

Comment: Connection has been stable in a different place. Could it be just interference all this time? OMG

Comment: Give it a day, let us know how it went :)

Comment: I've copied the above to an answer, just in case this solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the problem is hardware or configuration related, but just in case, to rule out interference issues: does this also occur when the laptop occupies the exact same location as one of the other devices that does have a stable connection? Even relatively small objects can cause this, if they contain sufficient metal.

Comment: Pretty sure now that it is my Jabra Speak 510 positioned too close to the laptop that caused this.

Comment: I guess that even though it'll operate at a different frequency range from WiFi (I assume it's BT?), it's still a tiny antenna. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem may also be with the **ipconflict** with your router. Try to manually set the **static** ip address of your pc and check if the problem occurs?
Here is a link to change to static ip in case you need.

[https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/how-to-change-your-ip-address-4-easy-ways/#:~:text=Windows%3A%20Make%20sure%20you're,new%20IP%20address%20in%20manually](https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/how-to-change-your-ip-address-4-easy-ways/#:%7E:text=Windows%3A%20Make%20sure%20you%27re,new%20IP%20address%20in%20manually).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Thank you for the suggestions! I will definitely care your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Lenovo P1 and I am also a user of Jabra Speak 510. Through similar trial and error (and also getting a replacement machine with the same outcomes) I ruled out the issue to be Jabra speak when connected to laptop's USB port. I came across this thread hoping someone figured out how to fix it, but in return just adding my comment here that I have exactly the same problem. Obviously, now being aware of the root cause I only use Jabra through bluetooth phone and laptop's wifi connection is fine.